# How to deploy REST API created using WSO2 EI to WSO2 API Manager

Tags: api, wso2, ei

I am new to WSO2 products and currently doing POC using EI & API Manager. I am using WSO2 EI to create REST API's and WSO2 API Manager to publish.

I have created REST API using WSO2 EI developer studio and deployed successfully into EI. Now I want to deploy same API in API Manager in order to publish and subscribe.

Any idea how to do this.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the Swagger definition from WSO2 EI as mentioned in [1]. Then using that Swagger definition you can create an API in WSO2 API Manager by following [2].

1. https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI600/Working+with+APIs#WorkingwithAPIs-GeneratingSwaggerdocumentsfortheAPIs
2. https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM250/Create+and+Publish+an+API+from+Swagger+definition